# Use hana::transform to transform types inside tuple in C++14

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I'm trying to use Boost's `hana::transform` to change the types inside a `hana::tuple`. As an example, say I have

```
constexpr auto some_tuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char *, bool>;
```

and I want to produce

```
constexpr auto transformed_tuple = hana::tuple_t<std::vector<int>,
                                                 std::vector<char *>, 
                                                 std::vector<bool>>;
```

**Attempt 1**

The solution seemed easy to me: Use `hana::transform` and make the applied function return `hana::type_c<std::vector<decltype(T)::type>>`. However, I can't make this work:

```
constexpr auto transformed_tuple = hana::transform(some_tuple, [](auto T) {
    using inner_type = typename decltype(T)::type;
    return hana::type_c<std::vector<inner_type>>;
});
```

This has the problem that the lambda expression is not a `constexpr` - and I want to stay in C++14, i.e., lambdas can't be `constexpr`.

**Attempt 2**

My next thought: What if I wrapped the `hana::transform` into a `decltype`, and then use `hana::type_c` on that? This way, the lambda never needs to be evaluated (only its return type must be deduced), and `constexpr`ness should not matter:

```
constexpr auto transformed_tuple = 
    hana::type_c<decltype(hana::transform(some_tuple, [](auto T) {
        using inner_type = typename decltype(T)::type;
        return hana::type_c<std::vector<inner_type>>;
    }))>;
```

However, now I run into the problem that lambda-expressions may not appear in an "unevaluated context".

Is my approach completely wrong? Should I use something else than `hana::transform`?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**:

Sample code:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

#include <vector>

constexpr auto some_tuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char *, bool>;

/** What I want:
 *
 *   constexpr auto transformed_tuple 
 *       = hana::tuple_t<std::vector<int>,
 *           std::vector<char *>, 
 *           std::vector<bool>>;
**/

#if ATTEMPT1
    constexpr auto transformed_tuple = hana::transform(some_tuple, [](auto T) {
        using inner_type = typename decltype(T)::type;
        return hana::type_c<std::vector<inner_type>>;
    });

#elif ATTEMPT2
    constexpr auto transformed_tuple = hana::type_c<decltype(hana::transform(some_tuple, [](auto T) {
        using inner_type = typename decltype(T)::type;
        return hana::type_c<std::vector<inner_type>>;
    }))>;

#endif
```

Comment: Can you make the code self-contained

Comment: Sure - basically you just have to write `int main() {}` below it and it should make for a complete C++ program. Of course it doesn't compile, since both my attempts above have the aforementioned problem. I'll append that to the post.

Comment: thanks for the edit. No worries, SSCCE is contained, not "running". Just helps others jump in (without them having to reinvent the includes, aliases etc. you used (they are sometimes part of the problem, by the way)_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.Hana has [`hana::template_`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Metafunction.html#ga246419f6c3263b648412f346106e6543) for applying types to a template which returns a type.

```
#include <boost/hana/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace hana = boost::hana;


int main() {
    constexpr auto some_tuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char *, bool>;
    constexpr auto expected_tuple = hana::tuple_t<std::vector<int>,
                                                  std::vector<char*>,
                                                  std::vector<bool>>;

    constexpr auto transformed_tuple = hana::transform(some_tuple, hana::template_<std::vector>);

    BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(transformed_tuple == expected_tuple);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Boost.Hana really has basically everything. I'll make this the accepted answer, because it's a lot cleaner, thanks!